# Drupal 7 site login works on XAMP localhost windows 7, but login doesn't work on UNIX

Tags: users

The problem that I'm having is that of the LOGIN functioning on my site.  On my laptop, localhost, the site works fine and logins work with no problem.  When I port the site over to our UNIX server, the site works fine EXCEPT I cannot login.  None of the logins work.

I've tested the DB, by using the DB on UNIX instead of localhost, and again, no problems.

I've Googled this issue and none of the suggestions have worked, i.e. make sure rewrite_mod is on, change permissions, etc.

Has anyone encountered this issue?  If so, how were you able to resolve it?

Again, its strange because there are NO problems with the site on my localhost, but the login doesn't do anything on UNIX, the login screen just reloads.

Thanks,

- KP

Comment: have you looked at the log files yet?

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the log files on the UNIX machine, and there are no errors.

Comment: have you set your $cookie_domain to the new domain?

Comment: After several days of heartache and pain, I finally found a post that provided a solution:
The issue was caused by Suhosin that was in the PHP5.4 package.  After removing Suhosin, I can successfully login.
The solution I found is at the following URL: http://www.rdlt.com/drupal-7-unable-to-login-on-centos.html